# How to filter an associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have to deal with a refactoring, to reduce the number of lines of code in PHP, to filter an associative array.
So I'm making a select from DB in MySQL, to get an associative array. So my "Object" has a category and a surname field.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $array[] = $row['category'];
        $array[] = $row['Surname'];
   }
```

I want to obtain from this array, as many other sub-array, splitted by the category. I mean the category Array identification may be:

```
$categories = array("A","B","C","D");
```

So what I want, is to obtain one Array for each Category, which contains all the Surname, of that category. 
So suppose that the method works, something like that:

```
$arrayFiltered = method_filter($array_asso,"A");
```

At the end I want something like that:

```
    foreach ($categories as &$value) {
       $arrayFiltered = method_filter($array_asso,$value);
       my_method_which_needs_the_filtered_array($arrayFiltered);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need proper normalized table structure in DB !! This approach you have(store data in comma separated values per record) will give you  lot of headache

Comment: The DB has a table, which is: Category, Surname as field. Right now works, that I'm making for each category, a query, but this add some delay and the code could be improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sergeant's approach is the easiest. Just for the sake of it, here is an approach with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) (just in case you have to have an unfiltered array as well):

```
$array = [];
$categories = array("A","B","C","D");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $item = [
        'category' => $row['category'],
        'surname' => $row['Surname']
    ];

    $array[] = $item;
}

$categorized = [];

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categorized[$category] = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($category) {
        return $item['category'] == $category;
    });
}
```

Here is a proof of concept without the need of a database connection:

```
$categories = array("A","B","C","D");

$array = [
    ['category' => 'A', 'Surname' => 'A Name 1'],
    ['category' => 'A', 'Surname' => 'A Name 2'],
    ['category' => 'B', 'Surname' => 'B Name 1'],
    ['category' => 'B', 'Surname' => 'B Name 2'],
    ['category' => 'B', 'Surname' => 'B Name 3'],
    ['category' => 'C', 'Surname' => 'C Name'],
];

$categorized = [];

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $categorized[$category] = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($category) {
        return $item['category'] == $category;
    });
}

print_r($categorized);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => A
                    [Surname] => A Name 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category] => A
                    [Surname] => A Name 2
                )

        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [category] => B
                    [Surname] => B Name 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [category] => B
                    [Surname] => B Name 2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [category] => B
                    [Surname] => B Name 3
                )

        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [category] => C
                    [Surname] => C Name
                )

        )

    [D] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as i get you  - you need one array which will contain all the `surname` `category` wise so that you can access them easily. This should help -

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $categories[$row['category']][] = $row['Surname'];
}
```

Simply store the category as `key` and all the `surname` as values to that `key`.

Comment: So, the last part of the code, should be: foreach ($categories as &$value) {
      my_method_which_needs_the_filtered_array($categories[$value]);
} isn't it ?

Comment: if `$categories[$value]` contains the category. :)